# How to filter or drop a value based on the previous one using Deedle in C#?

Tags: c#, filter, functional-programming, data-analysis, deedle

I am dealing with data from sensors. Sometimes these sensors have blackouts and brownouts, in consequence I can have the following kind of Time Series in a Frame, let's call it "myData":

[7.438984; 0,000002; 7.512345; 0.000000; 7.634912; 0.005123; 7.845627...]

Because I need only 3 decimals precision, I rounded the data from the frame:

```
var myRoundedData = myData.ColumnApply((Series<DateTime, double> numbers) => numbers.Select(kvp => Math.Round(kvp.Value, 3)));
```

I get the columns from the frame and filtered the Zeros "0.000":

```
var myFilteredTimeSeries = from kvp in myTimeSeries where kvp.Value != 0.000 select kvp;
```

So, my Time Series is partially filtered: 
[7.439; 7.512; 7.635; 0.006; 7.846...]

However, the value "0.006" is not valid!

How could I implement an elegant filtering syntax based on the previous value, something like a "percent limit" in the rate of change:

if (0.006 / 7.635) * 100 < 0.1 then ---> drop / delete(0.006)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the keys is to stay focused in methods that involve the value and its "neighbourhood", just like @tomaspetricek pointed before (Thanks!). 
My goal was to find a "free-of-noise" time stamp or keys to build a Frame and perform an AddColumn operation, which is by nature a JoinKind.Left operation.

To solve the problem I used the Pairwise() method to get focused on "Item1" (current value),  and "Item2" (next value) as follows:

```
double filterSensibility = 5.0 // % percentage

var myBooleanFilteredTimeSeries = myTimeSeries.Pairwise().Select(kvp => (kvp.Value.Item2 / kvp.Value.Item1) * 100 < filterSensibility);
```

Here I could write the relation I wanted! (see question) Then based on the Time Series (example) posted before I got:

myBooleanFilteredTimeSeries = [FALSE; FALSE; FALSE, TRUE; FALSE...]

TRUE means that this value is noisy! So I get only the FALSE boolean values with:

```
 var myDateKeysModel = from kvp in myBooleanFilteredTimeSeries where kvp.Value == false select kvp;
```

I created a frame from this last Time Series:

```
myCleanDateTimeKeysFrame = Frame.FromRecords(myDateKeysModel);
```

Finally, I add the original (noisy) Time Series to the previously created Frame:

```
myCleanDateTimeKeysFrame.AddColumn("Column Title", myOrginalTimeSeries);
```

...et voilà!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look just at the previous/next value, then you can shift the series by one and zip it with the original. This will give you a series of pairs (a value together with the previous/next value):

```
var r = actual.ZipInner(actual.Shift(1));
```

If you want to look at more elements around the specified one, then you'll need one of the windowing functions provided by Deedle:

- [Floating windows and chunking](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/csharpseries.html#Floating-windows-and-chunking)

The simplest example would be to use `WindowInto` to get a value together with 4 values before it:

```
var res = values.WindowInto(5, win => 
   // 'win' is a series with the values - do something clever here! 
);
```